# Getting a number of same values in multi-dimensional array

Tags: php

Basically I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
   Array
   (
       [action] => call
       [when] => today
   )
   Array
   (
       [action] => call
       [when] => today
   )
   Array
   (
       [action] => message
       [when] => today
   )
   Array
   (
       [action] => facetime
       [when] => tomorrow
   )
)
```

What would be the most appropriate way to count the most repeating action and how many times it repeated? *Key 'when' does not matter.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might resort to some of the built-in array functions.

Extracting the values of the column `'action'` by using `array_column` and passing it to `array_count_values` will give us the frequency of each action.

If we then get the maximum number of occurrences by using `max`, we can use it to filter the associative array (with `array_filter`) to get those that occur most frequent.

```
$occurrences = array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'action'));
$max = max($occurrences);

return array_filter($occurrences, function ($val) use ($max) {
    return $val === $max;
});
```